# Invalid URL Pattern When Deploying To Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jsf-2.2, glassfish-4

I had a web filter to redirect from the login and index page if the user was already authenticated. Originally I had an invalid URL pattern. I fixed the invalid pattern and attempted to redeploy only to receive this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]
at org.glassfish.web.deployment.node.WebResourceCollectionNode.setElementValue(WebResourceCollectionNode.java:136)
```

I checked around in my application to see if I was missing something or had typed something else wrong. Eventually I removed the WebFilter class, removed it's mappings from the web.xml and attempted to redeploy and the same error continues to come up. Currently I am unable to redeploy the application at all.

I checked around with some Googling and came across [this](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20858) which seems to be a similar issue, but no resolution.

The full stacktrace:

```
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [NCW-war]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]
at org.glassfish.web.deployment.node.WebResourceCollectionNode.setElementValue(WebResourceCollectionNode.java:136)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.endElement(SaxParserHandler.java:583)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:863)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:318)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:245)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:665)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:391)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You, 
 -Jarrod

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>trontastic</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.SecurityException</exception-type>
    <location>/login-error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/unauthorized-access.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/unauthorized-access.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/page-not-found.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Installations</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Installations</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/installations/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>Installations</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Administrator</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Administrator</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/NCW-war/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Project Management</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>project-management/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Analyst</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Analyst Pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/analyst/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Analyst</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>WAN Analyst</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>WAN Analyst Pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/analyst/wan/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>WAN Analyst</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Voice Analyst</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Voice Analyst Pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/analyst/voice/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Voice Analyst</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Project Manager Pages</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Project Manager Pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/project-management/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>Project Manager</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>LDAP</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/index.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login-error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>Installations</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>Analyst</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>WAN Analyst</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>Voice Analyst</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>Project Manager</role-name>
</security-role>
```

There should be no filter in there at this time.

Comment: Remove the `<security-constraint>` tag named `Administratorr` and its corresponding `<security-role>` for test and try again to deploy your application. It's suspecious

Comment: I removed it and redeployed and it deployed with no issues. I added it back to verify once again, issue arose. Removed it once again and created administrator security constraint and role again and deployed it with no issue. I hadn't changed anything in that role or constraint within the past couple of days. The extra resource collections were an attempt to resolve a weird problem with displaying resources on certain pages. Well anyways, thank you for the fix. If you post it as an answer I will accept it since it resolved the problem. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The web resource collection named `Administrator` has a `<url-pattern>` tag that its content has no leading slash. That means instead of `/project-management/*` it's just `project-management/*`. It seems that a url pattern has start with a leading slash. All other url-patterns in your web.xml are started with `/` except the `Administrator` one. Maybe this is the root cause of your problem. However I'm not sure it's a Glassfish problem or is part of Java EE spec.

Comment: That definitely works. I got to looking at the first class in the stack trace on grepcode and the `setElementValue(XMLElement element, String value)` method is supposed to prepend the "/" if it's missing, though only for Servlet 2.2 web apps. It is odd though that the error didn't present itself sooner as that url pattern had been in there for a couple of days. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score -1):

**

```
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It might be helpful to add a little bit more detail about why this is a good answer or how it solves the problem.  That way other people that come across this answer can have some more context and possibly upvote your answer.